# How do I synchronize sites/default/files wtith a AmazonS3 bucket?

Tags: backups

I need to sync sites/defalut/files with a amazons3 bucket. I found the [AmazonS3](https://drupal.org/project/amazons3) module, which replaces the storage location, while I still want to use the files at sites/defalut/files.

I want to use AmazonS3 as a sort of backup, and not as a storage solution. The files will not be served from it.

How can I do this?

I also found the [Storage API](https://drupal.org/project/storage_api) module.

Comment: Why not doing it on the system side? It sounds like you want to periodically copy the files to a remote server. You can use rsync to do so. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351190/syncing-local-and-remote-directories-using-rsyncsshpublic-key-as-a-user-differ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the need is to occasionally copy files from a directory to a corresponding directory on S3, you can use S3 CLI from AWS.

```
It provides a recursive copy:
aws s3 cp /tmp/foo s3://bucket/ --recursive
```

Reference: s3 — AWS CLI 1.2.13 documentation : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/

I programatically called this once using the [shell-exec from python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) and invoking the CLI commands.

The long route require the use of AWS S3 REST API (or one of the client SDKs). I havent done this myself, but it is possible since the CLI itself is implemented this way. May be you can take a look at the [CLI code on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/tree/develop/awscli)

Comment: I'd like to do this programmatically

Comment: Edited the above answer to include that.